# Do apk files have to be named the same for updates to work?

Tags: android, google-play

When the .apk is uploaded does it always have to be "app.apk" or can I upload "app v1.apk" followed by "app v2.apk"?

Does the name make any difference or is it just based on the info in the manifest?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about releasing app on google play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**. It won't make any difference if you change the name of apk.